# when try to fast refresh it give error in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I created a mv also have log file but I can't do fast refresh it will give error like-

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
 
 << continue close current delete fetch lock
insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
merge pipe purge
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Post a reproducible test case.  It appears that you have a syntax error but with no code, it is unlikely that anyone is going to guess what you've done wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

exec dbms_mview.refresh('mv_emp_fast','f');
--if log file not available for the base table then we can't do fast refresh

it is solved i was commented  beside of my query thats why it was give error after remove comment it work fine....thank you